# Neo4j cypher - "where edge.property = false" brings also true

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the picture below, both of the marked edges has a property: verified = **true** the rest of the edges are false.
In the following query, I'm asking only for verified = **false**.
n the picture, you can see that true **and** false returned.

```
match (a:GraphTarget)-[o:owner_of]->(b:Account) 
match (b)-[e:friend_of]->(m:Account)  
where e.verified = false 
return a,o,b,m,e;
```

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're seeing this in the Neo4j Browser, then the behavior here is because by default the browser will issue an additional query after the one you execute, to find all relationships between the nodes returned, whether you asked it to or not. While this is good for graph exploration and for checking out your results, it interferes when you don't want all relationships between the nodes returned, or you were only filtering for a subset.

You can disable this by going into the browser preferences (gear icon in the lower left), scroll to the bottom of the preferences panel, and uncheck the "Connect result nodes" checkbox. Then run your query again and check the results.